# Can not query on ID property graphQL Neo4j Databases

Tags: neo4j, graphql, apollo-server

I have a Neo4j database I can't do a "where" on the ID type of graphQL.
Anyone have any idea why?
thanks in advance

I have that

```
type DueDiligences {
  ddId: ID!
  counterPartyRisk: String
  countryRisk: String
}
```

when I query on String no problem

```
query Query {
  dueDiligences (where: { counterPartyRisk: "Hight" }){
    ddId
    counterPartyRisk
  }
}

//response
{
  "data": {
    "dueDiligences": [
      {
        "ddId": "1",
        "counterPartyRisk": "Hight"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

but when query in ddId I have empty response

```
query Query {
  dueDiligences (where: { ddId: "1" }){
    ddId
    counterPartyRisk
  }
}
//response
{
  "data": {
    "dueDiligences": []
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @John
How was your ddId created? This may happen if the ddId exists as an Integer in Neo4j Database as GraphQL Id type gets mapped to a string.

Comment: I create with cypher
->(`DD02`:DueDiligences {ddType: "Onboarding", ddStatus: "Open", ddId: 2, counterPartyRisk: "Medium", countryRisk: "Hight",

Comment: Please, try using `ddId: "2"` when creating it (or use Int type instead of ID in graphql).

Comment: With string is good :D

Thx you

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a mismatch between the `ID` graphql type (string) and the, manually created, id in the database (`int`).

When querying the database, even if using the same name, an int will not match a string.

To fix this, either the Cypher created ids should be created as strings, or the typedefs should define id as an Int:

```
type DueDiligences {
  ddId: Int!
  counterPartyRisk: String
  countryRisk: String
}
```

Comment: I change my ID  on string it's work better thank you very much

Comment: If this answer solves your comment, please, mark it as accepted so it may help other people with the same problem